# In Alfresco, is there a way to undeploy a definition from java script?

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I am looking for a way to undeploy a definition (more precisely: workflow) from java script. I am aware of the **workflow** object, but from what I can see on [Workflow JavaScript API page](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Workflow_JavaScript_API) it cannot be used to undeploy something. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Java API within Alfresco JavaScript by using the following 'trick':

```
var ctx = Packages.org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
var wfService = ctx.getBean('WorkflowService');
wfService.undeployDefinition(workflowDefinitionId);
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to use var `wfService = ctx["getBean(java.lang.String)"]('WorkflowService');`, becuase `getBean` is an overloaded method and `ctx.getBean('WorkflowService')` seems to pick the wrong overload (i.e. `getBean(String name, Object... args)`).